# Do SLOs measure failed requests when a service is down?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud, and I need to measure how often my service is available / down. SLOs seems to be what's come up in search results. It seems like you can pretty easily create an SLO based on request failures.

So the problem is, let's say I'm using something like Google Cloud Run. What if my region is down, or there is an issue with Cloud Run. Will my requests that fail even be registered?

Internal Monitoring like Google seems to be providing with SLOs feels like a flawed approach. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things. SLO have to measure the real business/user impact of your service.

If you use the SLO Feature on Cloud Run, and Cloud Run (or its region) is broken, indeed, you should miss a part of the information.

If you set SLO on a HTTPS Load Balancer (with your Cloud Run service as a Severless NEG backend service), you won't have that king of flaw. The service being global, it will trace all the requests, even if a region or the service is down.

But in that case, the SLO is global to 1 or several services, not specifically to only one.

---

SLO is an indicator to drive your decisions and your actions. It's important to well define what you want to measure, minimise, protect, to set it correctly and act accordingly.